# EJB @Singleton @WebListener annotated class cannot be deployed in WAR to JBoss 7.1

Tags: web-applications, singleton, ejb, jboss7.x

I am developing example of EJB 3.1 in Netbeans 8, using JBoss 7.1:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html

Based on specification of EJB 3.1, it should be possible to have enterprise beans in web module. I've got Singleton session bean in web module, see this part of example:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html#Exercise_3a

Application is deployable if I use `@Singleton`, `@LocalBean` annotations. 
If I add `@WebListener`, it cannot be deployed, error says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018043: ejb.SessionManagerBean has the wrong component type, it cannot be used as a web component
```

Can anybody help? 
Note: Example is demonstrated on Glassfish server, I have to use JBoss 7.1. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: No idea whether the standard requires that these annotations should be combinable, or if that's a Glassfish extension, but [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/172892?tstart=0) a workaround is suggested (quoting: `A web event listener is a different component type as opposed to an EJB. You can create a separate web event listener which injects the EJB.`)

Answer (score 0):

JBoss doesn't seem to allow a WebService or WebListener to also be an EJB..

As suggested above the solution is to create a separate `@RequestScoped` `@WebService` or `@WebListener` that injects and invokes the EJB method.